# Format Adjustment for VBA-WEB dictionary to JSON Body

Tags: json, vba

I asked a question before, but I didn't ask it well... so after I did some more homework I realised I need help with the conversion of VBA dictionary into a specific JSON format to be sent as the Body of an API POST query.

Here is what I have:

```
Dim Body As New Dictionary

Body.Add "applicationId", "customsHub"
Body.Add "exportAsContentType", "NOT_ZIPPED_SINGLE"
Body.Add "documents", New Dictionary

With Body("documents")
    .Add "documentIds", New Dictionary
    
    With Body("documents")("documentIds")
    .Add "documentId", "491e2229-471a-4b18-907a-0e25a312e5a7"
    End With
    
End With
```

Output:

```
{
  "applicationId": "customsHub",
  "exportAsContentType": "NOT_ZIPPED_SINGLE",
  "documents": {
    "documentIds": {
      "documentId": "491e2229-471a-4b18-907a-0e25a312e5a7"
    }
  }
```

What I need to get -

```
{
  "applicationId": "customsHub",
  "exportAsContentType": "NOT_ZIPPED_SINGLE",
  "documents": 
  {
    "documentIds": 
    [
      {
        "documentId": "491e2229-471a-4b18-907a-0e25a312e5a7"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I add this nested array as part of the VBA dictionary pre-conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[]" characters in Json means an array. So you should create the last `New Dictionary` inside an array:

```
Sub createDict_REturnJson()
  Dim Body As New scripting.Dictionary

  Body.Add "applicationId", "customsHub"
  Body.Add "exportAsContentType", "NOT_ZIPPED_SINGLE"
  Body.Add "documents", New scripting.Dictionary

  With Body("documents")
    .Add "documentIds", Array(New scripting.Dictionary) 'place the dictionary in an array
    
    With Body("documents")("documentIds")(0) 'place the item as the array first element:
    .Add "documentId", "491e2229-471a-4b18-907a-0e25a312e5a7"
    End With
    
  End With

  Dim Json As String ' to test the output:
  Json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Body, 2) 'supposing that you use JsonConverter module...
  Debug.Print Json
End Sub
```

To better catch the idea you can replace this part:

```
  With Body("documents")
    .Add "documentIds", Array(New scripting.Dictionary) 'place the dictionary in an array
    
    With Body("documents")("documentIds")(0) 'place the item as the array first element:
      .Add "documentId", "491e2229-471a-4b18-907a-0e25a312e5a7"
    End With    
  End With
```

with the next one, adding two dictionaries in the array, the first one keeping two keys (IDs) and the second one only one (only for didactic purpose...):

```
  With Body("documents")
    .Add "documentIds", Array(New scripting.Dictionary, New scripting.Dictionary) 'placing two dictionaries in the array
    
    With Body("documents")("documentIds")(0)
        .Add "documentId", "491e2229-471a-4b18-907a-0e25a312e5a7" 'first dictionary first key
        .Add "documentId2", "testID2" 'first dictionary second key
    End With
    Body("documents")("documentIds")(1).Add "DocumentID3", "TestID3" 'second dictionary first (single) key...
  End With
```